# Remove HTML tags from javascript output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I looked around stackoverflow but I couldn't find an answer that solved my problem. I hope I can explain it so you all understand what I'm trying to do... (If more info is needed, please let me know).

I have a piece PHP script that adds and removes content from an session array. Right now this is the code for this script:

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product): ?>
    <p style="font-size:1.2rem"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product); ?></p>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Using Javascript I echo this to a `textarea` where it returns the values.

**Javascript**

```
$('.my-subject').click(function(){
    var title = $(this).attr('value');
      $("textarea#thema").html(data); 
})
```

Right now it returns the value with the HTML Tags `<p>`...`</p>`.
How can I get it to return the value's with no HTML tags and a line break at the end? I tried using:

```
$("textarea#thema").text() + '\n';
```

But that didn't work, this still shows the `<p>`-tags and no line break.

I also saw some codes like this:

```
function removeTags(){
    var txt = document.getElementById('myString').value;
    var rex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
    alert(txt.replace(rex , ""));
}
```

But I don't know if I can use that for my code and how to do this... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Make a regular tag in memory (no need to put it on the page at all). Then insert the HTML as you've done above. Then get the text. Because it's a form element, it's all seen as text, which is why it's all returned. In a normal element (eg. a <div>) the HTML structure is actually parsed, so then you can get the text and do whatever you like with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `data` is a string containing markup in the form `<p style="font-size:1.2rem">STUFF HERE</p>`, repeated, and you want to get just the `STUFF HERE` part.

The reliable way to do that is to parse the HTML and extract the text from it:

```js
// The data
var data =
    '<p style="font-size:1.2rem">First</p>' +
    '<p style="font-size:1.2rem">Second</p>' +
    '<p style="font-size:1.2rem">Third</p>';
// Parse it
var elements = $.parseHTML(data);
// Convert that to an array of the text of the entries
var entries = elements.map(function(element) {
  return $(element).text();
});
// Get a string of the array entries joined with "\n"
var value = entries.join("\n");
// Done!
$("#output").val(value);
```

```html
<textarea id="output" rows="4"></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That can be written more concisely, but I kept the parts separate for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It does indeed remove the HTML tags from the output. But alas this does break my adding and removing code. The items aren't added nor removed anymore...

Comment: @Steggie: We can only work with the information in the question.

Comment: I know. But it would be far too long of a question to explain. Your efforts are greatly appreciated tho. This is a though one...