# Javascript: how to convert an element into an HTML-evaluated string?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's a simplified example of what I'd like to do:

```
var footnote = somewhere.innerHTML    // This is <q>the note</q>.
var result = ???(footnote)
target.setAttribute("title", result)  // This is "the note".
```

I've tried various methods and functions for the "???", but end up with either the raw tags displayed in the title, or with plain text and no quotation marks.

Other than processing all the inner tags myself, is there a way to convert an element into a string that contains how it would appear when HTML expanded?

Clarification:

I thought it was obvious from the "I have" and "I want" values indicated in the code comments, but this is what I want to do:

- I have an element (say a `<p>` if you need a specific type)
  that has content "`This is <q>the note</q>.`"
- I want something that will convert it into a string suitable for use in a `title="..."` attribute in some other element.
- Displayable internal tags (in this specific example `<q>`) need to be HTML-interpreted so that they display as actual quotation marks, ideally handling nested quotations.
- innerHTML conversion to string leaves the raw tags in place.
- innerText conversion to string ignores the tags and produces no quotation marks.
- Is there some other way of doing the HTML interpretation other than by writing my own function to process it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove HTML tags from javascript output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079784/remove-html-tags-from-javascript-output)

Comment: have you tried DOMParser?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the `q` tag you're actually adding a text node(this is what you get with `textContent, innerText, etc`) that has two CSS pseudo-elements around it, the open and closing quotations.

Neither pseudo-elements nor pseudo-classes appear in the document source or document tree. They basically don't actually exist in the DOM and are therefore not selectable/won't show up in any values of the element properties.

In short, using `<q></q>` is more semantic mark-up, but if you're looking to represent those quotations outside the scope of the view you may want to use the traditional `&quot;`

example:

```js
let p = document.querySelector("p"), div = document.querySelector("div");
div.title = p.textContent;
console.log(div.title);
```

```html
<p>&quot;Example Text&quot;</p>
<div></div>
```

Additionally, though I will say that I don't recommend it, if you really wanted to keep what you have and you're not too concerned with optimization you could simply use a replace:

```js
let p = document.querySelector("p"), div = document.querySelector("div");
div.title = p.innerHTML.replace(/<q>|<\/q>/gmi, '"');
console.log(div.title);
```

```html
<p><q>Example Text</q></p>
<div></div>
```